# Building block components for robot sensors and controllers

Tags: pic, sensor, motor, robotics, software

I'm planning on building a robot using Microchip PIC 16-bit MCUs, which I'm familiar with, and for which I have supporting hardware (demo boards, programmer, debugger, etc). After spending hours online understanding the open-source robotics scene, I've understood that most robotics projects aim to create robots that drive around, hear spoken commands, speak, and the like. I'm currently looking at something a lot simpler. My robot simply needs to read some sensors and move some motors. Is there an online library of open-source building blocks such as motor control, sensor interface, etc, that I can easily utilize on my current hardware? (PIC 24/32 or dsPIC). Obviously the Arduino scene has a lot of more code that can be reused, but I'm not planning on using an Arduino. Or should I? Tell me your views. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This question would be a good fit for the upcoming [Robotics SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/40022). Don't forget to go over there and 'Commit' to the proposal, so we can bring it into existence.

Comment: And also, @Geotarget: do consider Arduino. Which platform you choose to learn won't make too much difference once you spend enough time, but there are lots of robotics (and other) projects that are well-documented by Arduino users on the net. You can also start experimenting with [the Roomba](http://www.irobot.com) as a base: optionally even [with the Arduino](http://www.netfluvia.org/layer8/?p=127).

Answer (score 2):

The [Derbot robot](http://www.embedded-knowhow.co.uk/Derbot.htm) from University of Derby UK uses PIC Microprocessors for motor and sensors. I purchased the book [Designing Embedded Systems with PIC Microcontrollers](http://www.embedded-knowhow.co.uk/Book%202%202nd%20Ed.htm) which uses the Derbot and PIC as examples. I purchased the Derbot kit direct from the author of the book. The Derbot uses [Pumpkin Salvo Realtime OS](http://www.pumpkininc.com/) which is interfaced from C++. I am currently looking at [ROS Robot Operating System](http://www.ros.org/wiki/) capability and how hard to send messages to the Pumkin OS.